# MongoDb multikey index- sparse, unique, and growth questions

Tags: mongodb, indexing

For the [first pattern example of Mongodb Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)-

I have some questions on creating a multi key index on `book` array field for publisher `O'Reilly Media`:

For learning purposes, I am going to pretend in the future that the book array will only grow **at most** by 5 elements so I want to **focus only on this pattern** using the array:

1. When I add a objectId to the book array, will it automatically index the new element?
2. When I create `db.publishers.createIndex(books)`, do I want to make
   the background true so it doesn't block when I add to the books
   array later down the road and it indexes the new value?
3. I see the `unique` value is false by default. I am confused about
   this because I do not know the internal workings of MongoDb indexes.
   Wouldn't the unique value need to be true on the `books` array?
4. For`sparse`, why would I use it and why is it set to false? The
   `books` array is already a specified field.
5. If I deleted a element of the array, would the size of the index
   automatically decrease?
6. I'm assuming if I modify a book document later on it will not effect
   write performance since it's objectId was already indexed before in
   the publisher book array, correct?

   ```
   {
      name: "O'Reilly Media",
      founded: 1980,
      location: "CA",
      books: [12346789, 234567890, ...]
   }

   {
       _id: 123456789,
       title: "MongoDB: The Definitive Guide",
       author: [ "Kristina Chodorow", "Mike Dirolf" ],
       published_date: ISODate("2010-09-24"),
       pages: 216,
       language: "English"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MongoDB would automatically add the books ID to the multikey index. However, this index does not include the actual book document, of course.
2. The block only occurs when the index is created, not when items are added (albeit there is a very small overhead fit putting new items into indices). Imagine you already had 10k publishes with 200k books each - indexing those would simply take a while, either blocking any operation, therefore being faster, our doing it in background.
3. `null` values are unique values, too. So you could not have two publishers without a published book.
4. Sparse indices were used to save precious RAM. If you had millions of documents of which only a fraction had a certain field, it would simply be a waste of RAM to have a couple of million `null` entries. Nowadays, partial indices are preferred, which offer the same functionality as sparse induces and then some.
5. Yes, by the value you removed. If the array was emptied by that removal and you used a sparse or partial index, the according reference to the document would be removed, too.
6. Utterly, utterly wrong. An index is - heavily simplified - nothing else than a register of the indexed *field* and the position of the corresponding document in the data files. For the books array, that would be the publisher document containing the indexed value. Again, it is not the book document which gets indexed but the field holding references to book documents.  The reason why the books field gets indexed is that for a *given* book, the publisher can be found faster:

   ```
   db.publishers.find({books:someBookId})
   ```

   When editing a books document, you still would first have to find it and apply the changes which eventually need to be synced to disk (and even to the journal before). An index does not magically remove the need for persisting data.